# how to convert this curl command to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, centreon-api

I am using PowerShell and want to convert this curl command in PowerShell. It works well in bash

```
curl -s -H 'X-AUTH-TOKEN:'09f4a92e8fbfc9f9f530771ac32d37a1'' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1/centreon/api/beta/monitoring/services?search=\{"service.state":"2","service.is_acknowledged":"0"\}'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Curl.exe is also available for you to use

Answer (score 2):

Additional headers can be added to the `-Headers` property as hash table entries:

```
$result = curl -Uri $uri -ContentType application/json -Method Get -Headers @{'X-AUTH-TOKEN'='09f4a92e8fbfc9f9f530771ac32d37a1'}
```

You may want to try converting your uri string to type `[System.URI]`. This handles standard character replacement like ' ' to `%20`. I think `curl` does this already, but it may help you see if something is invalid:

```
$uri = [System.Uri]::new('http://127.0.0.1/centreon/api/beta/monitoring/services?search=\{"service.state":"2","service.is_acknowledged":"0"\}')

# check the output:
$uri.AbsoluteUri

http://127.0.0.1/centreon/api/beta/monitoring/services?search=%5C%7B%22service.state%22:%222%22,%22service.is_acknowledged%22:%220%22%5C%7D
```

Comment: PowerShell does not accept this part of the uri **{"service.state":"2","service.is_acknowledged":"0"\}'"**

Comment: @AdolfKu What version of powershell are you using? It powershell seems to accept it for me, but I don't have the actual webservice to test against. You may want to try converting it to URI first? Added to answer because it's kinda long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which worked for me.
i have Changed `{"service.state":"2","service.is_acknowledged":"0"\}`to
==> `{`"service.state`":`"2`",`"service.is_acknowledged`":`"0`"}"`

Thank you

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.